# Laravel new app-name command valet error

Tags: php, laravel-5

when I try to use Laravel new app-name

it gives me this error "Valet only supports the Mac operating system."
I'm on windows 10. this command was working before.

Answer (score 2):

The error message seem quite clear to me, also from the laravel docs (https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.2/valet):

> Valet only supports Mac

use composer to create a new application:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name 4.2.*
```

(from https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick#installation)